# What is the syntax (object).function called? and how does it work under the hood?

Tags: go

I stumbled across something in go that works, but I don't know what to call it. I haven't been able to see any examples of it being used in blogs, or in the documentation (probably because I don't know the right term to google). Anyways, here's a code snippet showing what I mean.

```
client := &http.Client{}
clientGet := (*client).Get

// this works, and is calling the Get function on the client object. but how?
resp, err := clientGet(client, "http://google.com")
```

It almost seems like a type alias, but I'm not sure it it? Also, how does this work under the hood? Is it using reflection to call the Get function and therefore less performant than simply calling `client.Get`?

Comment: It is called method value. See https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_values

Comment: *"// this works, and is calling the Get function on the client object. but how?"* -- No, it doesn't. If you had `clientGet = (*http.Client).Get` (a [method expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_expressions)) then it would work as you claim. But you have a [method value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_values) there, and that doesn't work as you claim: `clientGet(client, "http://google.com")` is a compiler error, you can see it here: https://play.golang.org/p/KPmGinhMO-Y

Comment: Thank you all for the super quick responses! I should have used the playground to compile my example before posting... But in this case It was actually good that it was a compiler error as it taught me more. @mkopriva would you post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `clientGet := (*client).Get` expression produces a [method value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_values) which, as already mentioned in the comments, causes the subsequent expression `clientGet(client, "http://google.com")` to fail to compile (too many arguments).

Perhaps you meant to use the `clientGet := (*http.Client).Get` expression, which is called a [method expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_expressions) and which produces a function that:

> ... is callable as a regular function with the same arguments as Get prefixed by an additional argument that is the receiver of the method, i.e. *http.Client.

<sup>quote adapted for context</sup>

with that function then, the subsequent expression `clientGet(client, "http://google.com")` compiles without error.

You can see the compiler error here: https://play.golang.org/p/KPmGinhMO-Y

Comment: Thanks! this was super helpful